# Finding and running a file

Tags: powershell

I am creating a script where it searches through a bunch of nested folders to find the newest version of a software, which are in .msi form. My code currently can find the file and output it, but is not able to run the file.

I can use Select in the last line for the ForEach to output the correct file but when I change it to Start-Process, I get bombarded by errors.

```
 $path="S:\\Releases\\Program"
 $NoOfDirs=Get-ChildItem $path -Directory

 ForEach($dir in $NoOfDirs){
     Get-ChildItem  "$path\$($dir.name)" -File -Recurse | 
     Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt ([DateTime]::Now.Adddays(-1))} | 
     Select-Object @{l='Folder';e={$dir.Name}},Name,LastWriteTime | 
     Sort-Object  -pro LastWriteTime -Descending |
     Start-Process -First 1
 }
```

Is there a different command I should be using when running .msi files?

Comment: I'd guess that `Start-Process` does not accept  `-First` parameter…

Comment: I tried to set a global variable to the output and then to start the process but still cannot, I know in a bat file I would have to call msiexec.exe to use it, but I was led to believe that powershell is able to run the .msi without it. I'm not sure if my info is correct on that though.

Comment: I'm not following the logic but a global variable would work. As @JosefZ mentioned, `Start-Process` does not accept `-First` as a parameter. If you get the value you want from within your `foreach`, you can assign the result to `$global:result` and call it outside of the `foreach` with `Start-Process $global:result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code has to *"search through a bunch of nested folders"*, I'd recommend using the `-Recurse` switch on `Get-ChildItem.`
Also use the `-Filter` parameter to have the search limited to .MSI files.

Something like this:

```
$path    = "S:\Releases\Program"
$refDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-1)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.msi' -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $refDate} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # create the arguments for msiexec.exe.
        # to find out more switches, open a commandbox and type msiexec /?
        $msiArgs  = '/i', ('"{0}"' -f $_.FullName), '/qn', '/norestart'
        $exitCode = Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $msiArgs -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
        if ($exitCode -ne 0) {
            # something went wrong. see http://www.msierrors.com/tag/msiexec-return-codes/
            # to find out what the error was.
            Write-Warning "MsiExec.exe returned error code $exitCode"
        }
    }
```

Comment: In case there are multiple versions changed in the last 24 hours, both would be started. With proper syntax: `|Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1` isn't that bad. (in addition to your enhancements +1)

Comment: This worked with installing it somewhat. This software prompts the user to give permissions to install 2 or 3 libraries so I believe this method is skipping over those prompts. Is there a way around this?

Comment: To answer my own comment for those needing an answer in the future, find the .exe on your hard drive for PowerShell and change the properties to always start with Admin Permissions.